# Spring Integration for Report orchestration workflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, workflow

**Problem statement:**

- I primarily work on Spring Boot and just started reading about Spring
  Integration for the below problem statement
- I need to develop a spring integration project which talks to 10 (10
  is an example here) different services using various modes of
  communication.
- These modes of communication can be REST API
  communication, Apache Kafka, Rabbit MQ, Redis Queues, AWS Lambda etc
- Let's say each of the 10 different services publish varied formats of
  reports Meaning service 1 publishes a report of json/xml/xlsx formats
  Service 2 publishes an xlsx report and so on etc
- The reporting customizations can vary for each of these services
- Let's say as and end user, I can choose to subscribe to any
  combinations of these reports, meaning I subscribe to services 1 with
  json and xml, service 4 with json, service 7 with xlsx
- Each of these services integration needs to be a workflow
  (`IntegrationFlow` in Spring Integration terminologies). There can be
  subworkflows during the integration with these services
- Whether a service should be triggered or not comes based on the
  report types the end user/customer has subscribed to

**Error Handling:**

- If any subset of the report fails after the default timeout, let's
  say a customer has subscribed to 6 reports, 3 of them succeeded and 3
  of them failed, then I need to return the succesfully generated
  reports back to the customer

**Here are my questions:**

- Is Spring integration a good framework of handling the above
  requirement?
- How do I orchestrate and handle the above requirements in a workflow
  driven model?
- Does Spring Integration offer better transaction tracing capabilities?
- Most of the examples given in GitHub are using XML configuration. I'm looking for suggestions/examples using the Java DSL Flow
- Please give me some references of a subset of these requirements
  implemented using Spring Integration?
- Any suggestions/feedbacks/queries/clarifications are most welcome!